# storing static resources of the web application

Tags: java, heroku, resources

I have a `Spring Boot` web application that I keep on `github` and `deploy` on `heroku`.

The html pages of the application are using static resources like `images` for example.

```
<img src="img/slide 1.jpg" class="image-holder" alt="First slide"/>
```

Originally I stored it `resources` folder in `src\main` of the project. But as the number of items grew I came to the conclusion that storing it like this is not that great because I neither want huge `github` repository nor huge `jar` files with resources.

So my question is - what should I do? Use some cloud storage like `s3`? Some existing storing service? Some `heroku` addon for that?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has the [Bucketeer addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/bucketeer). You can use this to serve assets directly from S3, or you can use the `public/` directory in your app to serve them like local files.

It might help to look at [Spring Content S3](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/refs/release/s3-index.html) if you want to interact with S3 directly.

Comment: Addon is not free so unfortunately I cannot use it. I guess I'll have to use some workarounds with existing free storages like google drive or mega. Or maybe store resources in the database directly as bytes